# Are there feminine and masculine versions for every adjective and noun?

Tags: sustantivos, adjetivos, género, neutralidad-de-género

I'm wondering if there are feminine and masculine versions of every adjective or noun like "Genio" and "Enfadado" ( Which are masculine I think ) and if not how are they used for opposite genders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are personal nouns in Spanish which are the same for masculine and feminine.

> [artista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3ryMAo1)
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que cultiva alguna de las bellas artes.

And you'll see it has the  `m. y f.` (masculino y femenino) in all its entries. You can have other examples like "[poeta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TUUD7eg)", "[testigo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZfWvJyK)" or "[pianista](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Srhdevx)". These are called "sustantivos invariables en género". These are **NOT** ["gender-neutral" nouns](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8295/5481).

You would have the same for some adjectives like "amable".

> Ella es guap**a** y amable, pero él también es guap**o** y amable.

These are called [adjetivos invariables](https://www.gramaticas.net/2012/05/ejemplos-de-adjetivos-invariables.html). Some other examples: feliz, idiota, inteligente, obediente.

Comment: Please note that "poetisa" is the usual feminine for the noun "poeta" (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=poeta).

Comment: True, and similarly many other nouns related to professions are [developing their own feminine forms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/11883/5481). Both "La presidente" and "La presidenta" are valid, much like "La poeta" and "La poetisa". Even "la juez"/"la jueza". ["Los sustantivos terminados en –l o –z funcionan para ambos géneros.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/11836/5481), pero algunos han desarrollado formas en femenino terminadas en "–a"

Answer (score 5):

Adjectives must match in gender and number with the noun they modify; therefore, all adjectives have masculine and feminine form. Nevertheless, some adjectives are invariable, meaning that the masculine and feminine forms are the same. For instance:

> El edificio azul --- La casa azul

As for nouns referring to people, some of them have masculine and feminine forms, which, again, can be the same or not. So we have:

- Variable: *El conductor* --- *La conductora*
- Invariable: *El artista* --- *La artista*

But some other nouns only have one form, which can be used for men and for women. Take into account that, in Spanish, grammatical gender has a strong correlation with sex, but does not always match. Some nouns, referring to people, which have only one gender:

> Judit Polgar fue un genio precoz del ajedrez.
>
> Tom Cruise es una estrella de cine.

Polgar is a woman and Cruise, a man, but you can use a masculine noun for her and a feminine one for him.