# How do i tell which noun is what gender?

Tags: género

This is sort of a beginner's question but I seem to have trouble understanding this. I can never remember *la* or *el* or all the other ones on which word they go on. There doesn't seem to be a rule for how to know, and I just can't figure it out, or remember. Any tips on knowing which is which, and why?? or how??

Comment: You were asking two questions in the title, but one question in the body of your post.  I've simplified the question to match the body.  If you want to ask the other question from your original title, just post another question.  Welcome to the site and thanks for your question. // I found an older Q-A that I think will address your question, and therefore I'm voting to close.  If that other page doesn't do the trick, please explain what is still not clear for you.  Thanks.

Comment: Also helpful: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/322/9385

Answer (score 0):

Probably the largest, and most difficult part of learning a language is plain old *memorization*. You need to memorize hundreds, thousands of words to be fluent.

When you learn english, you basically memorize how to pronounce every word, since there are no rules for pronunciation. In spanish, there are rules for pronunciation and accents, so you can **read** any word correctly if you know the simple rules, even if you don't know the meaning. On the other hand, you basically need to memorize the gender of every noun out there that **has** a gender. Since there are nouns that never have a gender: there is ***la*** guitarra, but there is no ***el*** guitarro.

There are also words such as ***la* lavadora** in México, are ***el* lavarropas** in Argentina. So you might be tempted to think appliances in Mexico are female, and they are male in Argentina. But you'd be wrong, since there is also ***la* licuadora** or ***el* televisor** in both countries. So yes, you also need to know which variation of spanish you are speaking, in order to know which word gender to use.

Oh, and gender can make a word change meanings significantly. ***La* puta** means something completely different from ***el* puto**.

As for *why* words have gender, I suppose the best answer is **because**. Also you seem to be confused by articles: *el*, *la*, *los*, *las*. English makes it easier with simply **the**, but Russian makes it even easier... with no articles at all. German, on the other hand...

Also, if you're an English speaker, you will be surprised that there is a past, present, and *future* tense, which in English it uses an auxiliary word, but in spanish it's a completely different conjugation: was, am, **will** be are fui, soy, *seré*.

Comment: This seems a bit tangential, and not focused on what OP is asking.